# Is there a SI unit for space-time?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, units, si-units

Space and time are routinely combined into space-time nowadays, which implies that the SI meter and second should be combined into a single SI unit such as [meter-second]. So far, I haven't come across such a SI unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So far, I haven't come across such a SI unit.

And you won't find one. The problem is that meters and seconds are inconsistent with one another, much as are the customary units of mass and force. With mass in pounds mass, force in pounds force, and acceleration in feet per second squared, one has to use the ungainly $F=\frac{196133}{6096}ma$ rather than the much more handy and consistent $F=ma$ used in the metric system.

In a consistent, relativistically correct system of units, the speed of light is identically one, and it is unitless. The speed of light in the metric system is 299792458 m/s. Think of that 299792458 as equivalent to the ungainly  factor of 196133/6096 that one runs into in American customary units.

Comment: This is a subtle point, at least it was for me, in that the conservative legacy of the SI unit system is holding back its more elegant relativistic development.

Comment: @JohnMcAndrew It's important to remember that the number one driving goal of the International System of Units is to aid commerce. That the SI should be science-based is a secondary concern. That commerce is a driving goal means that changes to the SI units, as happened a couple of years ago (20 May 2019), must be (nearly) consistent with prior definitions. I wrote *nearly* because one of the key drivers of that massive adjustment was that the old SI was not consistent with itself. In particular, the kilogram prototype and copies made from it exhibited time-varying masses.

Answer (score 1):

The units keep being 'meter'. Since the speed of light $c$ is a constant for all inertial observers, there's no problem in multiplying time by this number to get meters, that is

$$
ds^2 = c^2 dt^2 - dr^2
$$

$ds$ has thus units of length

Comment: Isn't it the other way around: units keep being 'second'? The SI unit for time counts 9,192,631,770 transitions of the Cesium atom as '1' second. One meter is then defined by one second and $c$ as a conversion factor.

Comment: @John meters and seconds can't be separated. They measure the same thing. One second was originally 1/86400 of one rotation of Earth, which is not very accurate. The modern definition of 1 second uses cesium as a more accurate timer than Earth rotations. Meters started as a fraction of distance from equator to pole. After several revisions it is now more accurately described in terms of wavelengths. Redefinitions increase accuracy to keep up with observations. That is to say, I agree with your question's premise. There should be a single unit for spacetime. *c* is often used as a unit.

Comment: @John -- Yet, like David mentioned, SI units aren't changed willy-nilly. Physicists crunching relativistic equations might use *c*, but in society units are sticky. The U.S. isn't going to switch to the metric system anytime soon and the rest of the world won't switch away from the metric system, nor should they. Don't get hung up on international units; use whatever units will simplify the problem. Make up your own units. Conversions between units are trivial.